# Ckeditor Get Content From Iframe

Tags: ckeditor

I have a iframe and i'm trying to use Dialog to get data in Iframe and output to current html, but i don't know how to get Ckeditor Content from the Iframe.

I tried to using `CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData();` but look like cannot get it.

This is my code:

```
<textarea class='editor' name='description' id='description'></textarea>

$( "#dialog_custom" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
height: 768,
width: 1024,
buttons: {
    Add: function() {
        var model = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#model').val();
        var product_id = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#product_id').val();
        var product_name = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#product_name').val();
        var qty = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#qty').val();
        var total = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#total').val();
        var category = $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#category').val();
        if(qty=='') { qty = '0'; }
        if(total=='') { total = '0.00'; }
        if(model=='') {
            alert('Please input the correct Model Number.');
        } else {
            $(".product").append(InsertTableGetFromIframe);

            $('.delete_custom_row').click(function() {
                if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete this data?")) {
                    $(this).parents('.custom_row').next('.parts_row').remove();
                    $(this).parents('.custom_row').remove();
                }
            });

            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#model').val('');
            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#product_id').val('');
            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#product_name').val('');
            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#qty').val('');
            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#total').val('');
            $('.dialog_custom').contents().find('#category').val('');
            $(this).dialog("close");
            i++;
        }
    },
    Close: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
});


$( "#open_custom" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog_custom" ).dialog( "open" );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the solution to get the content in the iframe, i used jquery to submit the form then POST the value on the field and get it by Jquery again.

It's the most simple way that i found, actually I think we have another way better to do it...